# Can't search track use access_token from Client Credentials Flow

Tags: spotify

Does anyone face the same problem like me: that I can't search for tracks use access_token got from Client Credentials Flow (it works before but till today it crashes).

If I request access_token by other ways and copy access_token and hardcode it works again

Answer (score 0):

This grants you access at all times:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials('your_client_id', 'your client_secret')
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
sp.trace=False
```

Then, test it:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    artist_name = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
    results = sp.search(q=artist_name, limit=20)
    for i, t in enumerate(results['tracks']['items']):
        print(' ', i, t['name'])
```